# node.js で、WordPressサイトで使っている MySQLに接続したい

Tags: mysql, node.js, wordpress

こんにちは。
WordPressが使っているDBを、
node.jsから接続し内容更新したいなと思っています。

ネットで出ている記事の真似で、動かしてみたのですが、動きません。
何か接続条件が足りないのかどうか、まったくわからないのですが
動かす方法があるでしょうか？

WordPressだと何らかのポート、あるいは、セキュリティなどがかかっている
ということがあるのでしょうか？

このやり方だと動かせない、
ということなど教えてもらえると助かります。

まず接続情報を知りたかったので
FTPで接続してWordPressのフォルダから
wp-config.php をみて、接続情報を得ました。

```
// ** MySQL settings ** //
/** The name of the database for WordPress */
define( 'DB_NAME', '<データベース名>' );

/** MySQL database username */
define( 'DB_USER', '<ユーザー名>' );

/** MySQL database password */
define( 'DB_PASSWORD', '<パスワード>' );

/** MySQL hostname */
define( 'DB_HOST', '<xxx.xxx.jp>' );

/** Database Charset to use in creating database tables. */
define( 'DB_CHARSET', 'utf8' );

/** The Database Collate type. Don't change this if in doubt. */
define( 'DB_COLLATE', '' );
```

次の記事をみて接続コードを書きました。

NoSQLじゃなくてMySQLを使いたい！Node.jsのmysqlモジュールの使い方 - WPJ
https://www.webprofessional.jp/using-node-mysql-javascript-client/

---

```
//app.js

const mysql = require('mysql');
const connection = mysql.createConnection({
  host: '<xxx.xxx.jp>',
  user: '<ユーザー名>',
  password: '<パスワード>',
  database: '<データベース名>',
  //port : 3306
});
connection.connect((err) => {
  if (err) throw err;
  console.log('Connected!');
});
```

このようなコードで
    node app.js 
とコマンド打って動かしたのですが、
タイムアウトして接続できないというエラーがでます。

ポートは、コメントはずしたりして動きましたが
結果は変わらずでした。

環境はWindows10です。

ご存知の方、おられましたら、よろしくお願いします。

Comment: MySQLサーバもWindows10で構築しているのでしょうか？

Comment: いえ、xserverに接続しにいっています。

Comment: xserverは外部と接続は一部を除きできないと思います。https://www.xserver.ne.jp/news_detail.php?view_id=1819 SSHポートフォワード等の設定はしていらっしゃいますでしょうか？

Comment: ！！！むむむ。そうなんですね。
全くやってないのとやり方がわからないのですが、調べてみます。
ありがとうございます。

調べて改めて情報あれば追記しておきます。